# How do I set up LiteIDE so that Golang identifier completion works across packages?

Tags: go, autocomplete, liteide

I am currently trying to use LiteIDE to edit golang code, and my question is about setting up LiteIDE so that identifier completion works when I have more than one package.

I have a directory structure like:

- myProject

  - stuff

    - various non-Go files
  - src

    - pack1

      - pack1a.go
      - pack1b.go
    - pack2

      - pack2a.go
      - pack2b.go

So in pack2a.go, I want to be able to type something like pack1.So and then press Control Space and get a list of pack1.Something and pack1.SomethingElse. However, I am not getting this (it does not list anything).

Does anyone know what I should be doing?

(I have asked a similar question previously for Intellij Idea).

Comment: I haven't seen a single decent working implementation of intellisense for Go. Good luck though. My experiences have been similar where it works in some scopes but not across the whole project.

Answer (score 0):

Try a `go install` of your app, then go back to your editor.

If `pkg2` has not been compiled at least once, `pkg1` wouldn't be able to do any completion from `pkg2` methods.